# The cost of maintaining VTOL devices

Tags: helicopter, vtol, thrust-vectoring, tiltrotor

Which device for VTOL flight costs the most to maintain for a given number of flight hours?  A tiltwing mechanism?  A 2D thrust-vectoring nozzle (vectoring only between VTOL position and cruise position)?  A helicopter rotor mechanism?

Comment: Helicopters are definitely the cheapest way to get VTOL but to compare with other methods would be tough.  You'd have to get numbers from VTOL machine in production and service, like an Osprey, and compare with a helicopter in the same weight class.